# Excel references from fixed cell to column end?

Tags: excel, reference, formula

I need an excel formula that calculates the SUM of all column cells from a fixed level until the last cell in the column. Like : SUM from S5 to the last S cell.
I tried : `SUM(S5:S)` but doesn't work.

There is a cell with the number of lines. Can I use a variable in the formula like : `SUM(S5:S & A1)` with A1 containing the number of lines ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might try `=SUM(OFFSET(S5,0,0,ROWS(S:S)-ROW(S5)+1))`

Comment: Thx, but doesn't work :/
`ROWS(S:S)-ROW(S5)` 
Doesn't return the number of lines ...

Comment: The expression `ROWS(S:S)-ROW(S5)+1` will return the number of rows from cell S5 to the last cell in column S (which is what you originally asked for when you posted the question).  If you want a different number of lines, simply replace this expression with the number you want.  For example, if the number you want is in cell A1, you could use the formula `=SUM(OFFSET(S5,0,0,A1))`.

Comment: Thx it works
PS : Should replace Coma by Semicolon
`=SUM(OFFSET(S5;0;0;A1))`

Comment: Whether it's a comma or semicolon depends on what's specified as the "list separator" by your regional settings in Windows (assuming you're using Windows).  Mine is a comma.  Yours must be a semicolon.  Sorry if the difference led to confusion.

Answer (score 4):

To sum all the cells from A2 to the end of column A, you can use

```
=SUM(A2,INDIRECT("A2:A" & ROWS(A:A)))
```

This will work even if you put it in cell A1.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: I recommend using `NamedRange`s and `=INDEX(NamedRange, ROW()):INDEX(NamedRange, COUNTA(NamedRange))`. This behaves well both when the input data changes (both in size and value) **and** when the spreadsheet changes (more/less columns/rows). You can use this construct as input to any function that takes an array as parameter, such as `XLOOKUP()`.

---

I was just looking today for a solution to this, and I came up with something based on `INDEX()` and named ranges, which I think it works better than `INDIRECT()`. The exercise is this:

**Part 1**: Create input array

- In a new sheet, start by creating a simple array of numbers. Go to cell A1 and enter `=SEQUENCE(10)`. This will create an array A1:A10 with numbers from 1 to 10.

**Part 2**: Solution based on `INDIRECT()`

- Go to cell B1 and enter `=INDIRECT("A"&ROW()):INDIRECT("A"&COUNTA(A:A))`.
- There are two parts to this: one before the colon, another after the colon. The final result you are looking for is A1:A10, correct?
- The part before the colon uses a fixed reference to the column letter, `"A"`, and the `ROW()` function to get the number of the current row -- just so that this solution works if your data does not start on the first row (just a detail, really). The `&` bit, in case you are not familiar with, is used to concatenate strings. In the end you are building the string "A1" from the fixed letter `"A"` and whatever number comes from `ROW()`.
- The part after the colon is similar but now we are trying to get the row number of the last item in the array we are processing. We do this by using function `COUNTA()` passing the array `A:A` as input.
- Great, you should see a copy of the input array on column B. To test, let us multiply the array by 2. Go to cell C1 and enter `=INDIRECT("A"&ROW()):INDIRECT("A"&COUNTA(A:A))*2`. Now you should see the input array doubled.

**Part 3**: Solution based on `INDEX()`

- This solution requires a named array. To do that, select column A. The name box (top right corner, close to the cells, below the ribbon) will probably show A1. Click there and give the range a name. For example, `NUMBERS`.
- Now go to cell D1 and enter `=INDEX(NUMBERS, 1):INDEX(NUMBERS, COUNTA(NUMBERS))`. You will get yet another copy of the input array.
- Finally, go to cell E1 and enter `=INDEX(NUMBERS, 1):INDEX(NUMBERS, COUNTA(NUMBERS))*2`. Yet another doubled array.

**Part 4**: Tests

- Ok first thing, dynamic operations should behave well when items are added or removed to the input array. Go to cell A1 and change the `SEQUENCE()` parameter to 5. Then to 20. All the other arrays from columns B to E should automatically be resized, which shows both solutions work.
- The final test: add a column before A. See what happens to what now will be columns C and D.

Yep, the solution based on `INDIRECT` does not behave well if we change the structure of the spreadsheet. There might be ways to solve this that I have not explored yet, but for now I will stick to `INDEX` and named ranges -- which, by the way, seem to be a cleaner and easier to maintain option as well. If anyone suggests a way to "fix" the solution based on `INDIRECT()` I can edit this.

More info on named ranges can be found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64).

Comment: Just wanted to point that it also works if you delete the named range, whether the column or just the name, and re-add it, whether on the same place or on a different column -- even on a different sheet!